An integral of the Riemann Zeta Function
Came across an integral involving the Riemann Zeta Function, and I've been struggling with it for two days.
Problem
The Improper Integral of the Riemann Zeta Function is given by
$$
\color{orange}{I}=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\sin(\color{red}{\pi}\color{blue}{x})\zeta(\color{blue}{x})\zeta(1-\color{blue}{x})
d\color{blue}{x}
$$
The result from Wolfram Alpha is $\pi$.
I use Cauchy's Integral Theorem and Residue Theorem to try to solve this integral
Let $f(z)=e^{i\pi z}\zeta(z)\zeta(1-z)$ and consider Integral Contour, then we have
$$
\oint_C f(z)dz=
\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz+
\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz+
\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz+
\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-R}^{+R}f(x)dx=
0
$$
By Small Arc Lemma we can obtain
$$
\lim_{|z|\to 0}\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz=
\lim_{|z|\to 1}\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz=
-\frac{i\pi}{2}
$$
If $J\equiv\int_\Gamma f(z)dz=0$ then when $R\to\infty$ we get
$$
\boxed{I=\Im\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\pi x}\zeta(x)\zeta(1-x)=\pi}
$$
But I'm not sure $J=0$ , because $\zeta(z)$ is Oscillating as $\Re(z)\to-\infty$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_{\Gamma}e^{i\pi z}\zeta(z)\zeta(1-z)dz\right|\le&\
R\int_0^\pi e^{-\pi R\sin\theta}|\zeta(Re^{i\theta})||\zeta(1-Re^{i\theta})|d\theta\\\\=&\
R\int_0^\pi e^{-\pi\sin\theta}\ |\zeta(Re^{i\theta})\zeta(1-Re^{i\theta})|d\theta\\\\=&\
\pi R\ e^{-\pi \color{blue}t}\ |\zeta(\color{red}\sigma+i\color{blue}t)\zeta(1-\color{red}\sigma-i\color{blue}t)|
\end{aligned}
$$

Note $\color{red}\sigma=\color{orange}R\cos\eta,\ \color{blue}t=\color{orange}R\sin\eta,\ 0\le\eta\le\pi$.

Additional
I tried to transform the original integral to a symmetrical form
$$
I=2\int_0^\infty\cos(\pi x)\zeta\left(\frac12+x\right)\zeta\left(\frac12-x\right)dx
$$

Obviously, the integrand is an even function.

Consider complex function
$$
f(z)=e^{i\pi z}\zeta\left(\frac12+z\right)\zeta\left(\frac12-z\right)
$$
and use the Rectangular Contours suggested by TravorLZH, I've got the following results
$$
\mathrm{v.p.}\int_0^\infty 
e^{i\pi x}\zeta\left(\frac12+x\right)\zeta\left(\frac12-x\right)
dx=
\frac{\pi}{2}-
\int_Lf(z)dz
$$
The upper bound of the RHS integral is
$$
\left|\int_Lf(z)dz\right|\le
e^{-\pi a}
\int_0^\infty
\left|\zeta\left(\frac12+x+ia\right)\zeta\left(\frac12-x+ia\right)\right|
dx
$$
I know
$$
|\zeta(\sigma+it)|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty|n^{-\sigma-it}|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\sigma}\quad\mathrm{for}\quad\sigma>1
$$
therefor
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|\zeta\left(\frac12+x+ia\right)\right|=1
$$
But when $\sigma$ is negative, $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ becomes very complex, and it has a strong oscillation.
Frankly, I don't think $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|$ is indeterminate when $\sigma\to-\infty$.
But the results given by WolframAlpha imply
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|\zeta\left(\frac12-x+ia\right)\right|=0
$$
I don't know why, It's a really Tricky Integral.

Maybe check out the following paper:
https://abel.math.harvard.edu/archive/213b_spring_05/growth_zeta_on_vertical_line.pdf

When dealing with $\zeta$ function, I would recommend using rectangular contours instead of circular contour as the growth results for $\zeta$ is usually formulated in the setting where the real part is confined in some fixed interval and the imaginary part goes to infinity.

TravorLZH您好。考虑过矩形围道，但为了得到题目中的积分，可能需固定虚部，不然将得到$$i\int_0^{\frac12}e^{i\pi x}\ \zeta\left(\frac12+x\right)\zeta\left(\frac12-x\right)dx$$

Thanks Nuke Gunray,  it`s very helpful for me.

But for the original integral, it seems that the imaginary part needs to be fixed and the real part grows.

@IceRain2024 Do you remember where you came across this integral?

@Max Muller https://www.zhihu.com/question/663206283

Have you tried playing around with Riemann's functional equation (and or Gamma reflection formula for the $\sin$) to get a maybe 'easier' form?

@FShrike Yes, I've got $$\sin(\color{blue}\pi \color{red}x)\zeta(\color{red}x)\zeta(1-\color{red}x)=(2\color{blue}\pi)^{1-\color{red}x}\ \cos\left(\frac{\color{blue}\pi \color{red}x}{2}\right)\ \Gamma^{-1}(1-\color{red}x)\ \zeta^2(\color{red}x)\$$

@FShrike I also get the growth rate of the $|\zeta(1-\color{orange}s)|$ where $\color{orange}s=\color{red}\sigma+i\color{blue}t$ (fixed $\color{blue}t$)
$$|\zeta(1-\color{orange}s)|=\mathcal O\left(|\color{blue}t|^{\color{red}\sigma-\frac12}\right)$$
Does this mean
$$\lim_{\Re(\color{orange}s)\to\infty}|\zeta(1-\color{orange}s)|=\infty\$$

Thanks everybody, I have already answered https://www.zhihu.com/question/663206283/answer/3588246098

If you have found an answer to your question, I would encourage you to write it up here if you have the motivation; it's totally ok to write an answer to your own question. It makes the answer much more accessible to others who might be interested (the page you linked requires a log-in to see your work).

I suspect that this numerical result may  not be $\pi$. Mathematica code Reap@NIntegrate[Zeta[x] Zeta[1 - x] Sin[\[Pi]  x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]] shows that Mathematica only sampled points between -11 and 11 during the integration, and NIntegrate[  Zeta[x] Zeta[1 - x] Sin[\[Pi]  x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},   WorkingPrecision -> 50] shows that with high working precision Mathematica founds that the integral may not converge.

@JieZhu that is important for me, thank you~
